# background-image: url( not showing image

Tags: html, background-image

Have a file in a folder with the name `WhatsApp Image 2022-07-28 at 14.41.17 (3).jpeg` Then when I try to show it in HTML with PHP

`<div class="h-50 " style="background-image: url(./uploads/<?= $images[$new['id']][0] ?>); background-size: cover;"></div>`

`<?= $images[$new['id']][0] ?>` is name of file `WhatsApp Image 2022-07-28 at 14.41.17 (3).jpeg`

With inspect element shows me the link `WhatsApp Image 2022-07-28 at 14.41.17 (3` and doesn't want to show me the image in HTML. When I change the name in the database and file name to `WhatsAppImage2022-07-28` this works.

Don't know what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler might not know how to deal with blank spaces in the file name. Sometimes an underscore will substitute though sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

If you must keep that file name, when trying to display the image use `%20` to replace the space characters